# ArcPy method for amending layer symbology heading

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, layers, symbology, legend

Is there an ArcPy method for amending the heading of a layer's symbology without having to amend the field name (which would be problematic)?

I know how to change the layer's name & the `classificationField` that the symbology refers to, but I cannot find any documentation on amending the field name in the TOC so that something more meaningful appears in the legend.

Comment: If the UI permits it, then this is a function of ArcObjects, but not all AO capabilities were ported to Python, so it's possible that you cannot do this directly in Python.

Comment: Take a look at the CIM document: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/python-cim-access.htm

Comment: I've voted to re-open this. I'm not sure how we expect someone to provide a code sample when they're asking "is it even possible to do a code solution" >> They don't know if a method exists. Hard to write code around that.

Answer (score 3):

From the [CIM](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/python-cim-access.htm) (Cartographic Information Model), I think the piece you want to modify can be found/updated with the following code

```
p = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject('CURRENT')
m = p.listMaps('MapName')[0]
l = m.listLayers('LayerName')[0]
cim = l.getDefinition('V2')
cim.renderer.groups[0].heading = "Symbolized by : {}".format(cim.renderer.fields[0])
l.setDefinition(cim)
```

You'll need to determine what exactly you want to put into the heading. You mentioned the field name -- I grabbed the field name from the first item in the fields list.